# link to mobile page of website doesn't work

Tags: html, mobile, hyperlink

I've built a separate mobile version of a website, but suddenly when I test one of my tabs (the tab named "videos") from the index page on my mobile phone, it now links to the full-sized video page from the normal website. It takes a very long time to load, but eventually the http://www.tygervinum.com/video.htm page loads instead of the http://www.tygervinum.com/m/video.htm page.

Another problem it that now when I click the tab called "books" from the index page on my mobile phone, it links back to the index page instead of the books page. The link works properly on the normal version of the website.

What have I done wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I clicked on the books link on the mobile version and it worked fine.

Comment: strange. on my phone and the phone of my friend when you click on the button for books you see for a split second in the URL bar http://www.tygervinum.com/m/books.htm then it immediately reverts to http://www.tygervinum.com/m/index.htm.

Comment: Removing tag that should not be used